# Angular DataTable DTColumnBuilder default value for null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

How to set a default value when null is occur

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
                    .fromSource('api/Restt/List');
                $scope.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('modifT').withTitle('Date & Time')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
                .fromSource('api/Restt/List');
            $scope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('modifT').withTitle('Date & Time').withOption('defaultContent', '-default value-')
```

Comment: Specifying the defaultContext in a column option or a columnDef option object is the proper way to accomplish this..